# Categorizing a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column that has university ranks as follows: `1,2,3,4,5,...,99,100,101-150,151-200,201-300,301-400,401-500,>500` and looks like this:

```
   Uni_Rank
    1
    3
    4
    101-150
    20
    22
    151-200
    201-300
    301-400
    10
    15
    44
    53
    70
    >500
```

I need to generate another column that would categorize them as follow: `1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, 41-50, 51-60, 61-70, 71-80, 81-90, 91-100, 101-150, 101-150,151-200,201-300,301-400,401-500,>500`

My problem is that I cannot categorize them into numbers as some as strings. So I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Step 1 would be to make them integers. And step 2 to use a bin.

Comment: also why is the step size for category not monotonic? is it intentional?

Comment: @AntonvBR That was my inclination. But I couldn't figure out how to convert them into numbers as some are strings, e.g. '101-150'

Comment: @anky_91 this is intentional, the categorizing is not linear.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this (just add more bin boundaries and labels as you wish)

I am assuming the string ranks are your eventual categories that you want

```py
df_train_final['uni_original'] = [1,3,4,'101-150',20,22,'151-200']
bins = [0, 10, 20, 30]
names = ['1-10', '11-20', '21-30']

df_train_final['uni_rank'] = df_train_final['uni_original'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else pd.cut([x], bins, labels=names)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first convert your strings to numbers (integers will do) and then apply a bin function (e.g. pd.cut).

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['1','3','4','10','101-150','151-200','>500','53','70'])
df = s.to_frame('Uni_rank')

# handle >500
df = df.replace('>500', '501')
# extract digits and convert to integer with regex
df['Uni_rank'] = df['Uni_rank'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)

# Create bins and labels
bins = [0,10,100,150,500,501]

labels = [
    '1-10', 
    '11-100',
    '101-150',
    '151-500',
    '>500'
]

df['Rank'] = pd.cut(df['Uni_rank'], bins=bins, labels=labels)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   Uni_rank     Rank
0         1     1-10
1         3     1-10
2         4     1-10
3        10     1-10
4       101  101-150
5       151  151-500
6       501     >500
7        53   11-100
8        70   11-100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
bins = [0,10,100,150,500] #you can add custom edges
labels = ['1-10', '11-100','101-150','151-500'] #make sure labels are 1 less than bins
```

---

```
m=pd.to_numeric(df.Uni_Rank,errors='coerce')
df.Uni_Rank.mask(m.notna(),pd.cut(m,bins,labels=labels))
```

---

```
0        1-10
1        1-10
2        1-10
3     101-150
4      11-100
5      11-100
6     151-200
7     201-300
8     301-400
9        1-10
10     11-100
11     11-100
12     11-100
13     11-100
14       >500
```